# Regular text font boldface subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, boldmath

I want to get a subscript in math mode to be both regular text font and boldfaced. Neither of the following does the job:

Codes 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$a_\text{\textbf{b}}$
\end{document}
```

Codes 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$a_\mathbf{\text{b}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `$a_{\textbf{b}}$` seems to work for me. Provided `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: Both your solutions lack a pair of curly braces around the subscript: you should say, for instance, `$a_{\text{\textbf{b}}}$`.  But as @cfr has noted, `$a_{\textbf{b}}$` suffices.

Comment: `$a_{\mathbf{b}}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a_{\textbf{b}}` is what you want. The following example loads a different text font, for comparison with the maths, and compares this output with that from `a\textsubscript{\textbf{b}}` in text mode, to show that the subscripts (but not, of course the 'a's) are the same. Finally, this is compared with some maths subscripts, just for comparison.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{venturis,amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $a_{\textbf{b}}$ a\textsubscript{\textbf{b}}  $a_b$ $a_{\mathbf{b}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: comparison]

The left shows the result with the suggested code. The next is the text-mode comparison (same 'b', different 'a'). Third is a simple maths subscript (same 'a', different 'b'). Finally, a maths-bold subscript (same 'a', different different 'b').

Answer (score 1):

**First you'd better make sure that your math font and text font use the same font family for example CMS default or Times.**

For your question, delete `\text{}`, and you will get what you want as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$a_\mathbf{b}$
\end{document}
```

And the effect is

[image]

By the way, you should understand `\mathbf{}` more clearly: it can produce bold and up shape English letters and numbers without any other commands. The following is a table for math fonts

[image]

which comes from Gratzer's book and so may have a different font from yours.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants: the bold 'b' is not using the text font. That's why I suggested `\textbf` and not `\mathbf`.

Comment: @cfr but in most cases, `\mathbf` using text font to make math letters bold and upshape unless you make different font settings for text and math.

Comment: Which is to say, it is *not* a text-mode 'b'. It is from the maths font. And that's not what the OP asked.